# Initialing ArrayList reference with null

Tags: java

```
public static List<String> li = null; // Error in this line "Syntax error ";"  "

li = new ArrayList<String>();
```

What's wrong with first line?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your class?

Comment: A guess: remove `public static`. This code must be inside a method.

Comment: I need to use li in another class. :(

Comment: put first line outside of a method or constructor or an initializer block means before the constructor and second line in a method or constructor or an initializer block. So you can you it in other class. see @Eran answer.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I put the second line in method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the two lines can be the source of the problem.

If those two lines are not inside a method, the second line is invalid (such a statement can only be inside a method, a constructor or an initializer block).

If those two lines are inside a method, `li` cannot have the modifiers `public` and `static`, since it's a local variable. The only modifier it can have is `final`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to instantiate a datafield ie. a variable of global scope it has to be done in one line.
If you wish instantiate it later, move:
li = new ArrayList(0);
into a method.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables also known as `static` variables are declared with the `static` keyword in a class, but outside a method, constructor or a block.